# relatedTo field visible in verify merge fields, but not in vf email

Tags: email, profile

I've a custom field which is not being populated in the visual force email which is send.

If I test the email template via `Setup > My Templates > Send test and verify merge fields`, the custom field `{!relatedTo.xxx}` is populated in the email. Though when we send the actual email, which is send via a trigger, the field is not populated.

The field is related to an object, which holds several custom fields. All the other fields are populated, except for the product.

It's working on the dev environment, but on the uat environment, it is not. So I think this is due to a setting.

I've checked the `Field-level security` and the `View field accessibility`. Those seem to be correct.

Any ideas?

Comment: does the running user have READ access to the record in question (check Profile and sharing settings)?

Comment: I had to go to the anonymous profile and enable read acces in public access settings. You put me in the right direction though. If you give an answer, I'll accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If an object has several custom fields and all but one populate on the email template, then the issue is most likely that the running user’s profile extended by any permission sets does not have read access to that field.

Note that the running user, if a Sites user, will have profile settings under Setup | Sites | Manage Public Settings.